# Usage of bootstrap carousel for non images

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

How can we use carousel for other elements than images? i like to use sliding property for tables. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't see images here https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The carousel slides whatever content is inside it.
[Even the official example does not use images:](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel)

Answer (score 0):

replace the img tags with tables tag. **

```
<div class="item">

<table class="table"></table>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Table</h3>
        <p>This is table</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**